# How to make a multi-select listbox selection required in a userform?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform with a multi-select list box.

The code I wrote expects the user to select two options.

I need that the user gets an error message only if they don't select at least one option.

I started with the code for a single-select list box error message. I tried making it >= -1 <0 <>-1 and none of them allow the user to select just one option.

The line in question is:

```
If ListBoxNextSteps.ListIndex <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "Please select next steps"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButtonSubmit_Click()

    'Requires specific fields to be complete before user can submit
    If ComboBoxDBN = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a DBN"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If TextBoxDate = "" Then
        MsgBox "Plese enter a date"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If CheckBoxCohort = False Then

        If TextBoxContactName = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please list school officials that you contacted"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If ListBoxSupportType.ListIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox "Please select a support type"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If TextBoxDiscussion = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please describe your discussion points"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If TextBoxLearn = "" Then
            MsgBox "Please describe what you learned about the school's challenges"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If (CheckBoxAdminDiff + CheckBoxConflict + CheckBoxShortage + CheckBoxDataSystems + CheckBoxOther) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please select at least one bucket"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If (CheckBoxOther = True And TextBoxIfOther = "") Then
            MsgBox "Please describe other bucket"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If ListBoxNextSteps.ListIndex <> 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please select next steps"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If ListBoxResolution.ListIndex = -1 Then
            MsgBox "Please select a resolution status"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End If


    'tells form to put responses in a long table
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    'Make Sheet1 (SchoolSupport) active so it knows where to put the responses
    Sheet1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True


    'Determine emptyRow so it knows where the next entry goes
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    'Transfer information from form fields to table cells
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBoxDBN.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBoxDate.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBoxContactName.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = ListBoxSupportType.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = TextBoxDiscussion.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TextBoxBestPractice.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = TextBoxLearn.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 15).Value = TextBoxIfOther.Value
    'Makes sure multiple selections appear in same cell
    If CheckBoxCohort = False Then
        Dim s As String, i As Integer
            With ListBoxNextSteps
                For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                    If .Selected(i) = True Then s = s & .List(i) & ", "
                Next i
            End With
        With Cells(emptyRow, 16)
            .Value = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        End With
    End If

    Cells(emptyRow, 17).Value = ListBoxResolution.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 18).Value = TextBoxEscalateTo.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 19).Value = ListBoxEscalateLocation.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = ListBoxEscalateStatus.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 21).Value = TextBoxPertinentNotes.Value

    If CheckBoxUnresponsive.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxCohort.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxAdminDiff.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxConflict.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxShortage.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxDataSystems.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = "Y"
    If CheckBoxOther.Value = True Then Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = "Y"

    'Saves workbook
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save

    Unload SchoolSupportForm

End Sub
```

I expect the ListBoxNextSteps error message to appear only if the user hasn't made any selection, but instead, it appears if the user hasn't made at least 2 selections.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Selected method of the ListBox object to check whether an item is selected.  The following code loops through each item in the listbox.  If an item is selected, the boolean variable itemSelected is set to True and the For/Next loop is exited.  After exiting the loop, if itemSelected is set to False, the message is displayed and then it exits the sub.

```
Dim itemSelected As Boolean
Dim i As Long

itemSelected = False
With Me.ListBoxNextSteps
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            itemSelected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

If Not itemSelected Then
    MsgBox "Please select next steps"
    Exit Sub
End If
```